# Differentiability of a Uniformly Convergent Series

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, uniform-convergence

I'm currently reviewing some elementary analysis (it's been a while), and I recall the tremendous significance of uniform convergence of a sequence of functions.

If memory serves (though I can't find the exact theorem in baby Rudin), the following holds:

Given $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Given

\begin{align} (1) \: \:f_k: A \rightarrow B, & \text{ differentiable on }A \\ 
              (2) \: \: F_n : A \rightarrow B  & \text{ by }   \\
                   & F_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}f_k(x)\\
              (3)\:\:F: A \rightarrow B & \text{ with } \\
                   & F(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}F_n(x)   , \:\forall\: x\in A.\end{align}
If $F_n$ converges uniformly to $F$ on A, then $F$ is differentiable on $A$, and

\begin{align} F'(x) =  & \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k'(x). \\ 
              \end{align}

I'm looking for an example that illustrates when this doesn't hold; in particular, I'm trying to find $f_k, A,$ and $B$ such that the above $(1), \:(2),$ and $(3)$ hold, however $F_n$ does not converge uniformly to $F$ on $A$, and as a result

\begin{align} F'(x) \neq  & \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k'(x). \\ 
              \end{align}

I've tried a few sequences of functions that I know are (and that I can show to be) pointwise convergent and not uniformly so, but I'm struggling to come up with a series of such functions.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Also, this is not homework.  It is merely for my own edification.

Comment: To see the trouble that can arise, consider $f_k(x) = \dfrac{\sin (k^2x)}{k^2}.$

Comment: I think that in your second point (2), it should be $f'_k $

Comment: @zhw.  So I can see that your $f_k$ is differentiable for all $k$ and $x$, and that its partial sum $F_n$ is bounded, but as far as whether $F_n$ converges pointwise or not (and thus, to what $F$) I cannot tell.  Does your function show that my initial recollection of this proposition is not true?

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Do I have the proposition stated incorrectly?  Do you mean that the conclusion is based on the premise of the uniform convergence of the sum of $f_k'$ rather than $f_k$?

Comment: @bloomers yes yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not enough for  $F_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)$ to converge uniformly to $F(x)$ to ensure that the series is termwise differentiable with

$$F'(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty f'_k(x).$$

The basic theorem states that if $F_n(x)$ converges at at least one point in $A$ and $F_n'(x) = \sum_{k=1}^nf'_k(x)$ converges uniformly on $A$ to $G(x)$, then $F_n$ converges uniformly to a differentiable function $F$. In this case $F'(x) = G(x)$ for all $x \in A$.

It is easy to find an example of a series that fails to converge uniformly and is not everywhere differentiable. Simply find a non-uniformly convergent  series of differentiable functions that converges to a function with a discontinuity.

Of more interest is a counterexample that presents a uniformly convergent series that fails to be differentiable at some point.

Take $A = [0,\infty)$ and

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}x\, ,\,\,\, n= 0 \\ -\frac{x}{(1+nx^2)(1+(n-1)x^2)} \, , \,\,\, n > 0 \end{cases}$$

Using a partial fraction decomposition we obtain a telescoping sum resulting in

$$F_n(x) =  x - \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x}{(1+nx^2)(1+(n-1)x^2)} = \frac{x}{1 + nx^2} $$.

Since $F_n(x)$ attains a maximum value of $1/(2\sqrt{n})$ at $x = 1/\sqrt{n}$, we see that $F_n$ converges uniformly to $F = 0$ and $F'(x) = 0$ on $A$.

However,

$$F'_n(x) = \frac{1 - nx^2}{(1+nx^2)^2} \to \begin{cases}1 \, , \,\,\, x = 0 \\ 0 \, , \,\,\, x >0 \end{cases},$$

and we see $\lim_{n \to \infty} F_n'(0) \neq F'(0)$.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you.