# Convergence and differentiability of an interative function

Tags: analysis, derivatives, uniform-convergence

Given a function $f_{1}(x)=\sqrt{x}, f_{n+1}(x)=\sqrt{x+f_{n}(x)}$ for $x \in[0, \infty)$. How can I prove if $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ uniformly or pointwise ? I tried with the quotient criteria to prove that $f_{n}$ converges. However $\frac{f_{n+1}}{f_{n}}>1$. Also how can I determine $f'$ or $f'_{n}$?

A rather theoretical question if $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ will $f'_{n} \rightarrow f'$? Keywords regarding the topics for further reading are also appreciated.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2364089/148510) is a counterexample where $F_n(x) \to F(x) \equiv 0$ for $x \in [0,1]$ but $F'_n(0) \not\to F'(0)$.