# What is an example of a convergent infinite series that is not term-by-term differtiable?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence

The textbook 'Applied Partial Differential Equations' by Richard Haberman (p. 115) states that "infinite series (even convergent infinite series) cannot always be differentiated term by term". Unfortunately, he does not offer such an example. What is an example?

Comment: If $\sum f_n$  and $\sum f_n'$ both converge uniformly  then $(\sum f_n)'$ =$\sum f_n'$

Comment: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~agk22/uniform.pdf shows that if the sum converges at one point and the sum of derivatives is uniformly convergent then you can term by term differentiate. You can find examples in any typical textbooks.

Comment: See this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2364089/148510) for an example of a series $F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)$ that converges for $x \in D$ but where there is a point $c \in D$ such that $F'(c) \neq  \sum_{n=0}^\infty f'_n(c)$ . We even have uniform convergence of $\sum f_n$ but $\sum f_n'$ does not.

Comment: The phrase "not term-by-term differentiable" has two possible interpretations: the terms themselves are not differentiable, or the terms of the series are differentiable but the sum of their derivatives does not always equal the derivative of the sum. Could you clarify which of these is correct?

Comment: @AlannRosas I believe the author is referring to the property of commutativity of the summation notation and the derivative operator. So when he says "term-by-term differentiation", he means that there is equality regardless of whether the summand goes through the differentiation or summation first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for $n\ge 0$ the function defined as
$$f_n (x)= \frac{n}{(n+1)(n+3)[\vert x\vert +1]}-\frac{n+1}{(n+2)(n+4)[\vert x\vert+1]}$$

For each $n$, $f_n (x)$ is not differentiable because of the absolute value.
Note that
$$f_0=-\frac{1}{8(\vert x\vert+1)}$$
$$f_1=\frac{1}{8(\vert x\vert+1)}-\frac{2}{15(\vert x\vert+1)}$$
$$f_2=\frac{2}{15(\vert x\vert+1)}-\frac{3}{24(\vert x\vert+1)}$$
$$\vdots$$

So the sum of the series
$$S_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n} f_i=\frac{n+1}{(n+2)(n+4)[\vert x\vert+1]}$$

Which means that
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} S_n=0$$
A convergent function.